# database desigining for city details from multiple web service

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

I am working on travel application, so we have to deal with different web services like GTA,  Gallileo, Kuoni  etc . for getting information regarding Hotel details.
Each web service has its own list of city code and city name.
I want to design a table to store the city details from different web service, after some research I came to these two approaches

1st approach

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
[CityID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CountryCode] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[AppCityCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[AppCityName] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
[GTACityCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
[GTACityName] [varchar](200) NULL,
[GWSCityCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
[GWSCityName] [varchar](200) NULL,
[KuoniCityCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
....
....
....
....
....
....
)
```

In this approach when ever a new webservice is added then two columns (city code and city name) corresponding to the webservice is added, due to this modification and there will be a change in stored procedure and in frontend application code.
There will be no duplication while loading the cities in the textbox

2nd Approach
WSSupplier table is used to store Webservice details like GTA, Gallileo..

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WSSupplier](
[SupplierID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[SupplierName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
[CityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AppCityCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
[AppCityName] [varchar](150) NULL,
[CountryCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
[WSSupplierID] [smallint] NULL,
[WSCityCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
[WSCityName] [varchar](150) NULL
)
```

In the 2nd approach the cities will be added row by row with corresponding web service supplier ID
If new webservice come then I don't have to modify the table structure or in frontend application.
While loading cities I have to use DISTINCT to load unique city in the textbox or dropdown in frontend

In both approach I am using Appcitycode and Appcityname this will load the city textbox or dropdown in the application. While selecting the Appcityname, it will get the corresponding web service city code and send it as request to the webservice to search a hotel in a particular city.

I want to know which will be the best approach or if there is any other good approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third approach would be to create an intersection table between your city table and your supplier table that lists the supplier's version of the city code.

Your city table would just have your own system's city identifier.  The city would appear only once.  Each time you add a supplier you insert new records into the intersection table with the city codes for the cities that supplier cares about.  The translation of a supplier city code to your internal city code is a simple lookup in the intersection table.

Consider something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WSSupplier](
[SupplierID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[SupplierName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
[CityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CityCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
[CityName] [varchar](150) NULL,
[CountryCode] [varchar](10) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SupplierCityCode](
[CityID] [int] NOT NULL,
[WSSupplierID] [smallint] NULL,
[WSCityCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
[WSCityName] [varchar](150) NULL,
FOREIGN KEY [fk_city] [CityID] REFERENCES [dbo].[City],
FOREIGN KEY [fk_supplier] [WSSupplierID] REFERENCES [dbo].[WSSupplier]
)
```

Comment: one more question i want to ask is I had added 10 cities in City(App) table..When i get the list of Cities from the supplier they have around 100 cities... so 90 cities are different and 10 are common with my App city..I had extracted the data from supplier city xml and loaded in a table with two columns CityCode and cityname..now  i want to insert the data into City table and SupplierCity table..how to do that

Comment: @SQL006 - If you defined foreign key references then you actually wouldn't be able to put data into the intersection table first without a matching city already there.  If you are looking for a way to figure out which cities in the intersection table don't appear in the parent table, you should Google `SQL WHERE NOT IN SUBSELECT` or have a look at this KB: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189062(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about application and database design. From the application design point of view try to abstract from database design and think about it as some storage for your business objects. From database design point of view your question is about Database normalization - start from [this article at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) as a gate to big world of database design. As for me:

```t-sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Supplier](
[SupplierID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[SupplierName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppCity](
[CityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CityCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
[CityName] [varchar](150) NULL,
[CountryCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SupplierCity](
[CityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SupplierID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[CityCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
[CityName] [varchar](150) NULL
)
```